# Assigning value to foreign key field

Tags: django, django-views

I'm having difficulty assigning a title to the UserService model, which is a foreign key to another model.

**models.py**

```
class IndustryService(models.Model):    
    industryname = models.ForeignKey(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class UserService(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    title = models.ForeignKey(IndustryService, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Here is the portion of code within the view that is failing:**

```
    industryservices = IndustryService.objects.filter(industryname=industry)

    for service in industryservices:                
        try:
            qs = UserService.objects.get(user=user, title=service.title)
        except: 
            userserv = UserService.objects.create(user=request.user)
            userserv.title = service
            userserv.save()
```

The error that I'm getting is as follows:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_userservice.title_id
```

Based on my testing, the way in which I'm assigning the value to the 'title' foreign key field is wrong (i.e. these 2 lines of code).

```
    service2 = IndustryService.objects.get(title=service.title)
    userserv.title = service2
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing two updates, unnecessarily. Either create the item in one go:

```
 userserv = UserService.objects.create(user=request.user, title=service)
```

or instantiate without saving and then save at the end:

```
userserv = UserService(user=request.user)
userserv.title = service
userserv.save()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I can always rely on your awesome advice!